# Unable to play mp3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

How to resolve this bug in Ubuntu 14.04
Rhythmbox requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the ubuntu restricted formats package...

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

But you can use "Movies" to play the MP3. That piece of software automatically scans for plugins.

mp3:

[image: searching]

[image: installing]

mp4:

[image: searching]

[image: installing]

Comment: Tried and get the following error E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras

Answer (score 0):

I installed VLC Player and it work's fine. It's command is:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```